# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '....' to data type int

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to create an Update Statement for my Table in **JavaFx** and I'm receiving following Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Ana' to data
>   type int.

I created the tables in SQL Server.In my database only age is from type int, everything else is String.

Here is my Code :

```
    public void handleUpdateAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String sql = "update users set name =?, age = ?, department=?, job=?,  contact = ? where userNo =?" ;
    try {

        String userNo = txt_userNo.getText();
        String name = txt_name.getText();
        double age = Double.valueOf(txt_age.getText());
        String department = txt_department.getText();
        String job = txt_job.getText();
        String contact = txt_contact.getText();
        p_stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);



        p_stmt.setString(1, userNo);
        p_stmt.setString(2, name);
        p_stmt.setDouble(3, age);
        p_stmt.setString(4, department);
        p_stmt.setString(5, job);
        p_stmt.setString(6, contact);
        int i = p_stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (i == 1)  {
        }System.out.println("Data Updated Successfully");
        loadDataFromDatabase();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but should the parameters not be in the same order that they are in the query? You add the parameter `userNo` first, but it's the last in your query. Considering that `'Ana'` is a name as well, which is the second parameter you add and the parameter for `Age` is the second in the query, I'm assuming this is a very safe guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parameterIndex` for `Statement.setString` indicates the lexical order of the parameter marker `?` in the query.  So `userNo` should be at the end.  EG:

```
    public void handleUpdateAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String sql = "update users set name =?, age = ?, department=?, job=?,  contact = ? where userNo =?" ;
    try {

        String userNo = txt_userNo.getText();
        String name = txt_name.getText();
        double age = Double.valueOf(txt_age.getText());
        String department = txt_department.getText();
        String job = txt_job.getText();
        String contact = txt_contact.getText();
        p_stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        p_stmt.setString(1, name);
        p_stmt.setDouble(2, age);
        p_stmt.setString(3, department);
        p_stmt.setString(4, job);
        p_stmt.setString(5, contact);
        p_stmt.setString(6, userNo);

        int i = p_stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (i == 1)  {
        }System.out.println("Data Updated Successfully");
        loadDataFromDatabase();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```